# GKLocalPlayer.LocalPlayer null on some simulators

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, game-center, game-center-leaderboard

I'm having this issue with integrating Game Center with my Monogame game.

What I have:

```
void InitGameCenter()
    {
        gameCenterManager = new GameCenterManager();
        SetAuthenticateHandler();
    }

    void SetAuthenticateHandler()
    {
        GKLocalPlayer.LocalPlayer.AuthenticateHandler = (ui, error) => {
            if (ui != null)
            {
                controller.PresentViewController(ui, true, null);
            }
            else if (GKLocalPlayer.LocalPlayer.Authenticated)
            {
                currentLeaderBoard = gameCenterManager.ReloadLeaderboard(leaderboardId);
            }
            else {
                var alert = new UIAlertView("Game Center Account Required", "Need login the game center!", null, "Retry", null);
                alert.Clicked += (sender, e) => {
                    //GKLocalPlayer.LocalPlayer.Authenticated();
                };
                alert.Show();
            }
        };
    }
```

**On some simulators it stops at first line of code in SetAuthenticateHandler() method throwing exception because GKLocalPlayer.LocalPlayer is null**.

**Where it works:**

iPad 2 (9.2) device
Every simulator of iPhone newer than 5 (iPhone 5s, 6, 6s whatever the iOS version).

**Where it doesn't work:** every iPhone simulator older tan 5s (iPhone 5, 4s)

The methods I showed you are in the AppDelegate's FinishedLaunching() method, since there is no ViewController.cs in Monogame.

Any clues?

Comment: FYI: GKLocalPlayer.LocalPlayer is returning a valid GKLocalPlayer object in my simulator (Version 9.2 (SimulatorApp-643)) for iPhone4s and 5.... using Xamarin.iOS Version: 9.4.1.24

Comment: Well I downloaded sample from the Internet and it returns valid LocalPlayer on every simulator :(
Maybe it's something to do with the fact I don't have ViewController.cs (I retrieve VC from UIApplication.SharedApplication.Windows [0].RootViewController when I need it, because in sample the code I use is in ViewDidLoad()...

Answer (score 0):

Could be a signature issue. Take a look at the [class details](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/MonoTouch.GameKit.GKLocalPlayer/). The signature changes at iOS 6.

From the docs:

```
//
// This shows how to authenticate on both iOS 6.0 and older versions
//
if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion (6, 0)) {
    //
    // iOS 6.0 and newer
    //
    GKLocalPlayer.LocalPlayer.AuthenticateHandler = (ui, error) => {

        // If ui is null, that means the user is already authenticated,
    // for example, if the user used Game Center directly to log in

    if (ui != null)
            current.PresentModalViewController (ui, true);
    else {
        // Check if you are authenticated:
        var authenticated = GKLocalPlayer.LocalPlayer.Authenticated;
    }
    Console.WriteLine ("Authentication result: {0}",err);
    };
} else {
    // Versions prior to iOS 6.0
    GKLocalPlayer.LocalPlayer.Authenticate ((err) => {
        Console.WriteLine ("Authentication result: {0}",err);
    });
};
```

Comment: I'm not using iOS <8.1 to test this. My minimum version is iOS 8.0.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so if anybody want to integrate Game Center with Monogame in the future there is a very simple solution for this (build in Monogame):

```
// Define gamer variable
SignedInGamer gamer;

// Launch Game Center authentication
gamer = new SignedInGamer();

// Later on, interact with Game Center in various ways
gamer.UpdateScore(category, score);
Guide.ShowLeaderboard();
Guide.ShowAchievements();
```

via picobots @ Monogame Community Forums ([link](http://community.monogame.net/t/game-center-confusion/640))